# Wordpress: Include a post by title into theme index.php and don't display it in single.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to display a "About me" Text on my index.php Wordpress page. I want to use the WYSIWYG editor from a posting. The text is paragraph and a ul/li.

1. How do I include this posting by the title "About me" (without loosing all <\br>? (I have tried `get_page_by_title( $slug, OBJECT, 'post');` <- but this removes all "<\br>"s).
2. How do I prevent user/robots from visiting the posting "About me" via single.php?

Answer (score 0):

This worked well: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-widget/ Registered sidebars for this.